# VLookup VBA autofill active column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to figure a way to make this formula autofill the activecolumn based on lookup value which is in column A or to return formula in the activecell so I can autofill it myself because at the moment its returning only result

```
Private Sub CommandButton_d_Click()
    Dim filename As String 
    Dim fullRangeString As String
    Dim returnValue As Variant 
    Dim wb As Workbook 
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range 
    Dim article As Range 
    Dim rng1 As Range 
    Dim acell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set acell = ActiveCell
    Set article = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
      FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xls", _
      Title:="Please select a file")
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("a1", _
      Range("a1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("a2", "av2")
    acell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(article, rng, _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1, rng1, 0), False)
    wb.Close False
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use *VBA Worksheetfunction* for your `VLOOKUP` at least. 
To accomplish what you need, you need to use *Range Object Formula Property*.

Try something like:

```
acell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & article.Value & "," & rng.Address(, , , True) & "," & _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1, rng1, 0) & ",FALSE)"
```

This doesn't cover the *Autofill* as I'm not sure what you want to do. HTH though.

Comment: Thanks for the reposnse. With your formula it returns the formula but it gives me the activesheet range, not the selected file one. I changed " & rng.Address & " with "," _
    & "[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address & " and try it. The problem is when I debug.print it the formula is correct "=VLOOKUP(M63485,[Inventory shops.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$Q$26939,8,False)" but when change back to aceel.formula on my activesheet the cell is empty

Comment: one more thing i forgot to put the strings on the array formula. this is the correct one but now it returns me N/A  "=VLOOKUP(" & article.Value & "," _
    & "'[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & "," _
    & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1, rng1, 0) & "," _
    & "False)". I try it manual doing the formula from excell worksheet then  I compare to the array formula that is returned to the formula tab and i was looking the same but still get N/A

Comment: @Anton You just need to set the *External Argument* to true. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i found a solution.

Here is the final code.

acell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & article.Address(False, False) & "," _
    & "'[" & rng.Parent.Parent.Name & "]" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address & "," _
    & Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox1, rng1, 0) & "," _
    & "False)"